# JSF Components alignment inside panelGroup

Tags: css, jsf, datatable, selectoneradio, center-align

I have a **selectOneRadio** element with *layout="custom"* inside a **dataTable**. Below is the xhtml code-

```
<p:dataTable var="varlist" value="#{testbean.testlist}">
    <p:column headerText="Choose Option" width="120">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{varlist.varlistValue}"
            layout="custom" required="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="10" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="20" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>

        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:radioButton id="opt1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" />
                <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="OPTION 1" styleClass="radiolabelOption"/>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" />
                <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="OPTION 2" styleClass="radiolabelOption"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<style type="text/css">
    .radiolabelOption {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

So this is how it appears in browser-

[image: image1-]

As we can see, the **outputLabel** appears to the bottom with respect to **radioButton**. But i want that to *look centre*, w.r.t **radioButton** as shown below -

[image]

I tried below lines of code like

> style="display:block; text-align:center"  OR
> style="margin: 0 auto;"

But none of them produces the desired result.

So How to do it?

Comment: I even tried to raise the height of outputLabel using   "margin-bottom:..px"   in the style. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `<h:panelGroup>` these styles

```css
.panelGroup{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Also, I recommend learning more about [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), it's really useful!

Comment: That's weird... this shouldn't do anything with margin. Didn't you type something wrong?

Comment: Looks like that 'display: flex' breaks it. Can you send me styles of 'panelGroup' from browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241898/discussion-between-pavel-schiller-and-satya-prakash-panigrahi).

Comment: I did a fresh build for my project & it worked as expected. My bad for not trying that earlier. Thank you :)